# file_get_contents() not working for 2 url's

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am using `file_get_contents()` function to get two webpages from Google. My code is:

`var_dump(htmlspecialchars(html_entity_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/search?q=moscow+russia&start=30'))));`

`var_dump(htmlspecialchars(html_entity_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/search?q=ice&start=00'))));`

The `file_get_contents` function works for the first URL but it does not work for second URL. What's the problem?

Comment: Is [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53243518/4529168) ok?

Answer (score 0):

It is because there is character, that can't be processed by `htmlspecialchars`. `file_get_contents` is working.

Try `ENT_SUBSTITUTE` option:

```
var_dump(htmlspecialchars(html_entity_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/search?q=moscow+russia&start=30'))));
```

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php